# Defaulting the following constraints to type 'Double' when using Scientific

Tags: haskell

I have two scientific numbers that are necessarily Integers that I want to convert to Ints, as below.

Please ignore code conventions and the idiomaticness of the code.

```
> import qualified Data.Vector as V
> import Data.Scientific

> cToTy (Array v) = case V.toList v of
>     [String nm, Number p, Number s] 
>      | all (==True) $ map isInteger [p,s]  -- We make sure they're always integers
>      , [pr,sc] <- map (forceEitherToInt . floatingOrInteger) [p,s] -- And then hack them out

> forceEitherToInt :: (RealFloat r, Integral i) => Either r i -> Int
> forceEitherToInt (Left _a) = 0 -- This shouldn't happen, so we'll default it to 0 all the time.
> forceEitherToInt (Right a) = fromIntegral a
```

However, I get this warning and I can't figure out how to rid myself of them.

```
JsonUtils.lhs:76:26: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ‘Double’
      (RealFloat r0) arising from a use of ‘forceEitherToInt’
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘forceEitherToInt’
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely
      ‘(forceEitherToInt . floatingOrInteger)’
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   a case alternative:
      [pr, sc] <- map (forceEitherToInt . floatingOrInteger) [p, s]
```

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Firstly, defaulting is (at least in this case) harmless. `p` and `s` is polymorphic - something like `RealFloat a => a`, but the return type of `forceEitherToInt` doesn't include that type, so the constraint must be discharged when `forceEitherToInt` is applied. To make your life simpler, the compiler guesses which type to use - and `Double` is not a bad choice. If you really want to get rid of it, give applications *or* the definition of `forceEitherToInt` a monomorphic type signature.

Comment: Do you need `forceEitherToInt` to have the restriction of `RealFloat`?  You aren't using it, you could just do `forceEitherToInt :: (Integral i) => Either r i -> Int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can explicitly cause an error if "neither should happen"; second, you can drop `RealFloat` as @bheklilr states; thirdly you can specify the double more concretely if you prefer the double; fourthly it can help with Hungarian notation if you write 'A from B' rather than 'B to A' in your names. So you could write for example:

```
intFromEither :: (Integral i) => Either Double i -> Int
intFromEither (Left d) = error $ 
    "intFromEither tried to coerce `Left " ++ show d ++ "` to an Int."
intFromEither (Right i) = fromIntegral i
```

You can replace the `Double` above with `x` to make it more general; the most general type signature here is `(Integral a, Num b) => Either t a -> b`.

Comment: I took your solution verbatim and I still get a warning, this time about Integer: `Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ’Integer’
      (Integral a0) arising from a use of ‘intFromEither’
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘intFromEither’
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely
      ‘(intFromEither . floatingOrInteger)’`

Comment: @Arnon Okay, so, I think that alleviating this requires a little teaching. Haskell has user-definable ambiguity; this feature is called "type classes". However, Haskell also allows you to define "defaulting" for these type classes (i.e. "hey computer, if you can't resolve the ambiguity just assume this..."). `RealFloat` defaults to `Double` and `Integral` defaults to `Integer`. Haskell is warning you that it is doing this as it does it, just in case it's not what you wanted. You can specify `Either Double Int -> Int` to make its choice explicit and then simplify `intFromEither (Right i) = i`.

Comment: I could've sworn I've tried that and it gave me warnings before - but it seems to work now. Thanks!